# Trying to make a function adding numbers recursivly from set values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function to add all numbers from start to stop (recursive_sumrange(start,stop). Some examples of output are as following.

recursive_sumrange(7, 2) >> 27

recursive_sumrange(2, 7) >> 27

recursive_sumrange(2, 2) >> 2

recursive_sumrange(-1, 1) >> 0

I've tried the following bit of code but, it doesn't add the last number in the range neither does it work if start value is bigger than the stop value.

```
def recursive_sumrange(start, stop):
    lst = ""
    if(start == stop):
        return 0
    else:
        lst = [elem for elem in range(start, stop+1)]
        return lst[0] + recursive_sumrange(start+1, stop)

print(recursive_sumrange(int(input("Enter start: ")), int(input("Enter stop: "))))
```

EDIT this is the solution that came up with:

```
def recursive_sumrange(start, stop):
    lst = ""
    if(start == stop):
        return start
    elif(start >  stop):
        lst = [elem for elem in range(stop, start+1)]
        return lst[0] + recursive_sumrange(start, stop+1)
    elif(start < stop):
        lst = [elem for elem in range(start, stop+1)]
        return lst[0] + recursive_sumrange(start+1, stop)

print(recursive_sumrange(int(input("Enter start: ")), int(input("Enter stop: "))))
```

Comment: Look at your code and think what happens for `recursive_sumrange(2, 2)`. Regarding `start > stop` you should check at the beginning and just swap the values then.

Comment: Look at the meaning of [start and stop on range](https://pynative.com/python-range-function/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I added a new argument called `first_itr` to handle if the numbers are given in the wrong order `(stop, start)` instead of `(start, stop)`

```
def recursive_sumrange(start, stop, first_itr=True):
    if first_itr:
        start, stop = sorted([start, stop])
    if start > stop:
        return 0
    else:
        return start + recursive_sumrange(start+1, stop, False)

print(recursive_sumrange(7, 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
def recursive_sumrange(start, stop):
    if start > stop:
        return sum([i for i in range(stop, start + 1)])
    else:
        return sum([i for i in range(start, stop + 1)])


print(recursive_sumrange(int(input("Enter start: ")), int(input("Enter stop: "))))
```

Comment: Hi i solved it but this code is more clean, but i don't like how it prints none after the sum is printed out, is there anyway to fix that.

Comment: Is this a recursive solution?!

Comment: @Pro-Grammer The None is being printed since the function doesn't return anything, to fix that either change the print statement to return in the function or remove the print when you call the function in the very last line